# jQuery - How do I stop a div from moving at all in a sortable interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to stop the pink part 1, part 2, part 3 from beign sortable as they are the headings for my columns and they need to stay in that exact fixed position. How can I do this ? I tried using Cancel but I didn't really know where to put it.

Also if by any chance you find any badly written stuff please excuse me and notify me if you have the time. I just started and I'm really bad at this.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    #main-container {
      background-color: green;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: auto;
    }
    .column-div {
      width: 300px;
      height: 100%;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .column-name {
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: pink;
    }
    .user {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: gray;
      border: 2px solid yellow;
    }
    #aqua {
      background-color: aqua;
    }
    #red {
      background-color: red;
    }
    #orange {
      background-color: orange;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main-container">
    <div class="column-div" id="aqua">
      <div class="column-name">
        Part 1
      </div>

      <div class="user">

      </div>

      <div class="user">

      </div>

      <div class="user">

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="column-div" id="red">
      <div class="column-name">
        Part 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-div" id="orange">
      <div class="column-name">
        Part 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".column-div").sortable({
        connectWith: ".column-div"
      }).disableSelection();
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you tried a condition?

Comment: Like and If/Else? No I haven't, and I really have no real idea how to impliment one in my current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an items that allows you to set a selector of the sortable 
here is a link to the documentation [sortable items documetation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items)

in your case it would be something like

```
$(".column-div").sortable({
    connectWith: ".column-div",
    items: '.user'
  }).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the cancel property to cancel the sorting of the column name

```js
$(function() {
  $(".column-div").sortable({
    connectWith: ".column-div",
    cancel:".column-name"
    
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    #main-container {
      background-color: green;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: auto;
    }
    .column-div {
      width: 300px;
      height: 100%;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .column-name {
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: pink;
    }
    .user {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: gray;
      border: 2px solid yellow;
    }
    #aqua {
      background-color: aqua;
    }
    #red {
      background-color: red;
    }
    #orange {
      background-color: orange;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main-container">
    <div class="column-div" id="aqua">
      <div class="column-name">
        Part 1
      </div>

      <div class="user">

      </div>

      <div class="user">

      </div>

      <div class="user">

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="column-div" id="red">
      <div class="column-name">
        Part 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-div" id="orange">
      <div class="column-name">
        Part 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I used the items property to apply the sorting only to the elements I wanted. In my case would cancel be better for me ?

Comment: should be the same

Comment: Thanks for helping me